# PHP right shifting and negative result?

Tags: php, bit-shift

I've run into a problem whilst converting some C code to PHP, specifically in the use of the right-shift operator.

**edit:** in the following examples, bit = 0;

Original C code:

```
p->param->outBits[bytePtr++] |= codeword >> (9 + bit);
```

PHP code:

```
$outBits[$bytePtr++] |= $codeword >> (9 + $bit);
```

If I start with `codeword` being 130728, in C I get the expected result of -1.  In PHP I get 255.  I understand this is something to do with arithmetic/logical shift differences, and the negative sign not being introduced as a result of the MSBs staying at zero.

Is there a "quick" way of doing the above in PHP that doesn't involve the shifting? eg via basic arithmetic or similar, that will give me the expected answer?

Comment: @stereofrog, just realised that the `outBits` memory is a load of char's, hence 8-bit and hence the difference in the results - thanks for pointing me towards writing a quick test case! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that PHP doesn't have a type `byte`, it only has `integer` which usually is 32 bits (not 8), so if you really need negative value there (the bits are correct anyway, because unsigned 255 is the same as signed -1), then you should probably add the missing 24 ones or use arithmetics to restore the negative value (255 is -1, 254 is -2 and so on i.e. 256 - x = -x).

Comment: That's what I was missing - see my comment above to @stereofrog.  Cheers! :-)